# Spring AOP with Around advice and @annotation not working

Tags: java, spring, annotations, aop

I am using Spring AOP for logging in my application. Here is the applicationContext.xml file

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.template" />
<context:annotation-config />
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.template.repository"/>
<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/template?autoReconnect=true"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="template"/>

</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
```

and my aopLogging.xml is

```
<bean id="aopLogging" class="com.template.log.AopLoggingAspect" />
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="false"/>
```

and my Aspect class is

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.StopWatch;

@Aspect
@Component
public class AopLoggingAspect {

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AopLoggingAspect.class);

@Around(value="@annotation(com.template.log.Loggable)")
public Object logAround(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable{
        Object retVal = null;
        try {
            StringBuffer startMessageStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

            startMessageStringBuffer.append("Start method execution :: ");
            startMessageStringBuffer.append(joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
            startMessageStringBuffer.append("(");

            Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
            for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                startMessageStringBuffer.append(args[i]).append(",");
            }
            if (args.length > 0) {
                       startMessageStringBuffer.deleteCharAt(startMessageStringBuffer.length() - 1);
            }

            startMessageStringBuffer.append(")");
            logger.info(startMessageStringBuffer.toString());
            StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
            stopWatch.start();
            retVal = joinPoint.proceed();
            stopWatch.stop();

            StringBuffer endMessageStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            endMessageStringBuffer.append("Finish method ");
            endMessageStringBuffer.append(joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
            endMessageStringBuffer.append("(..); execution time: ");
            endMessageStringBuffer.append(stopWatch.getTotalTimeMillis());
            endMessageStringBuffer.append(" ms;");

            logger.info(endMessageStringBuffer.toString());
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            StringBuffer errorMessageStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            logger.error(errorMessageStringBuffer.toString(), ex);
            throw ex;
        }
        return retVal;
}
}
```

and my Custom annotation is

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface Loggable {
}
```

and my Service class is

```
public class UserService {
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
@Loggable
public User getUserByUserId(Long userId){
return userRepository.findOne(userId);
}
}
```

The problem is that the logs are not getting printed. Please help me. Thanks in advance. Please do let me know if any other info is needed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you have forgot to import in your `applicationContext.xml` file the `aopLogging.xml` file. Try to add this to your `applicationContext.xml` file:

```
<!-- Import your AspectJ config -->
<import resource="classpath:aopLogging.xml" />
```

Comment: Hi, I have already tried with that and it isn't working either. Moreover when I run the test case using the same configuration, it is working absolutely fine. But when I deploy the same config war to tomcat, it is not intercepting the methods. Any clue regarding this?

Comment: Note:: I am not using interface's at all across all my application.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
@Around(value="@annotation(Loggable)")
public Object logAround(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable{
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Annotation

> @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
>   @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
>
> public @interface LogExecutionTime {   }

Then an Aspect

> @Aspect
>
> @Component
>   public class LoggingAspect {

Then a method in the Aspect

> @Around("@annotation(LogExecutionTime)")
>   public Object
>   logExecutionTime(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
>
> ```
>   long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
>
>   Object proceed = joinPoint.proceed();
>
>   long executionTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
>
>   LOGGER.info(joinPoint.getSignature() + " executed in " + executionTime + "ms");
>   return proceed;     }
> ```

Then use the Annotation Anywhere

> @PostMapping(value="/signup")
>   @LogExecutionTime
>   public @ResponseBody
>   ResponseObject register(User user){
>   }

Comment: Iam doing the same. But the annotation works for some methods and is not working for some. Not able to find patterns in the behavior. Any idea why this is happening?