# Spring AOP with custom annotation not working

Tags: java, annotations, aspectj, spring-aop

I have looked at every [example on stack exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19833482/spring-aop-with-around-advice-and-annotation-not-working) and on spring's example website and everything seems like this should work. I must be missing something simple

I have a custom annotation that ideally I would like to apply on either all methods of a class if the class is annotated or on any method annotated. Here is the aspect, test, and code:

Annotation

```
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

@Target({METHOD})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Monitor {
    String value() default "Monitor";
}
```

Aspect

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class LatencyAspect {

    @Autowired
    private Logger logger;

    @Around("@annotation(Monitor)")
    public Object logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Object retVal = joinPoint.proceed();

        logger.info("logged");

        return retVal;
    }
}
```

Test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class,classes = {LatencyConfig.class, LatencyTest.ContextConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan
public class LatencyTest {
    final static Logger log = mock(Logger.class);

    @Autowired
    private SomeClass someClass;


    @Test
    public void testExample() throws Exception {
        someClass.doSomething("foo");
        verify(log).info("logged");

    }

    @EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
    @Configuration
    static class ContextConfiguration {


        @Bean
        public SomeClass properties() {
            return new SomeClass();
        }

        @Bean
        public Logger log() {
            return log;
        }
    }


    public static class SomeClass {

        @Monitor
        @Transient
        public String doSomething(String whatever) {
            return "done";
        }
    }
}
```

Result

```
Wanted but not invoked:
logger.info("logged");
-> at org.bongiorno.latency.LatencyTest.testExample(LatencyTest.java:74)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

Links

[Actual source](https://github.com/chb0github/latency-monitor)

Comment: Do you have `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` enabled in your context?

Comment: Yes, I do. In the sample code you see I load 2 contexts -- it's on the other one. But, for argument sake I added it to the testing context as well. Same results

Comment: Is the `Monitor` annotation and the aspect defined in the same package?

Comment: Yup. I have even tried fully qualifying it

Comment: What about the `LatencyTest` class which defines the component scan root? Is that in the same package as the rest or a superpackage? Is component scan even picking up the aspect? You could change the aspect to use setter injection for the logger and break on the setter, or break on the field value change, so you actually make sure the aspect is picked up by spring component scan.

Comment: Tell you what: I will push the whole thing to github and send a link

Comment: Check the bottom of the post. I put a gihub link to the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring doesn't pick up the `@ComponentScan` annotation from a JUnit test class. Move the annotation to your `LatencyConfig` class or the test-local `LatencyTest.ContextConfiguration` inner configuration class.

Comment: Bang! That was it. In my previous tests I was calling out the application context via config